# Why is my third picture not inline with the other pictures?

Tags: html, css

I have some simple html and css styling and I am creating a site with articles and pictures. I don't understand why my third picture isn't aligned with the other photos. It's slightly higher, though it seems like the same size. How can I get it to to be aligned properly? I don't believe I'm doing anything differently with my third article/picture, so I don't understand why it looks different.

[image]

**index.html**

```
<html>
    
    <head>
        
        <title>Best News Ever!</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="This page is a webpage to learn html">
        <meta name="keywords" content="html5,udemy,learn code,">


        <meta name="author" content="Reza Zandi">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial=scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

    </head>

    <body>
        <header id="main-header">
            <h1>Best News Ever!</h1>

            
        </header>



        <section id="top-stories">
            <article>
                <div class="article-image" style= "background:url(dog.jpg)"  ></div>
                <h3>Dog kidnapped by other dog</h3>
                <p>California is no stranger to dog nappings, however, this one takes 
                    the puppies cake... <a href="#">read more..</a></p>
            </article>
        </section>

        <section id="top-stories">
            <article>
                <div class= "article-image" style="background:url(chocolate.jpg)" ></div>
                <h3>Chocolate is actually good for you</h3>
                <p>Scientists have discovered a new propery in chocolate this is good for you. 
                    They discovered that... <a href="#">read more...</a></p>
            </article>
        </section>

        <section id="top-stories">
            <article>
                <div class= "article-image" style="background:url(cat.jpg)" ></div>
                <h3>Cat steals catnip from pet mart</h3>
                <p>A cat in Dallas Texas broke into a petsmart and stole the entire supply of catnip they had.
                    Now that location is struggling to replace the... <a href="#">read more...</a></p>
            </article>
        </section>



    </body>


    <footer>
        <br/><br/>
        <center>&copy;2017<br/>
            <a href='#'>Terms of service</a>

        </center>
    </footer>
</html>
```

**styles.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sriracha&display=swap');


body h1 {
    font-family: 'Sriracha', sans-serif ;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;

}



#top-stories{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;

}

section {
  max-width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
}




article img {
    max-width:100%;

}

.article-image{

    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center !important;
}
```

Comment: Note: You are using the id `top-stories`  three times - that's invalid HTML. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues going on here, like duplicating an ID. That being said, you can get what you want by adjusting the width and using `vertical-align: top;`

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/harcfs0u/40/

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Best News Ever!</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header id="main-header">
      <h1>Best News Ever!</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="top-stories">
      <article>
        <div class="article-image" style="background:url(dog.jpg)"></div>
        <h3>Dog kidnapped by other dog</h3>
        <p>California is no stranger to dog nappings, however, this one takes
          the puppies cake... <a href="#">read more..</a></p>
      </article>
    </section>

    <section class="top-stories">
      <article>
        <div class="article-image" style="background:url(chocolate.jpg)"></div>
        <h3>Chocolate is actually good for you</h3>
        <p>Scientists have discovered a new propery in chocolate this is good for you.
          They discovered that... <a href="#">read more...</a></p>
      </article>
    </section>

    <section class="top-stories">
      <article>
        <div class="article-image" style="background:url(cat.jpg)"></div>
        <h3>Cat steals catnip from pet mart</h3>
        <p>A cat in Dallas Texas broke into a petsmart and stole the entire supply of catnip they had.
          Now that location is struggling to replace the... <a href="#">read more...</a></p>
      </article>
    </section>

  </body>


  <footer>
    <br /><br />
    <center>&copy;2017<br />
      <a href='#'>Terms of service</a>
    </center>
  </footer>

</html>


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sriracha&display=swap');


body h1 {
  font-family: 'Sriracha', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;

}

.top-stories {
  vertical-align: top;
}

section {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
}

article {}

.article-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the section class of CSS file, Try using display property with inline-flex. I am attaching you stackblitz link here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-c9mqfu

```
section {
  max-width: 33%;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work because now it just flips the problem, the first two are higher than the third one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the vertical alignment of inline-blocks is by default at their baseline, which in this case is the last line of your text. To fix that, add `vertical-align: top` to the CSS for `section`:

```
section {
  max-width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

(And as I wrote in the comments, don't use an ID more than once - use a class instead)

Answer (score 0):

u can know the differ between grid and flex in this link [differ between flex and grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Relationship_of_Grid_Layout)

```css
section {
  max-width: 33%;
  display: inline-flex; // or used  display: inline-grid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed extra text in 3rd image p and then your code worked fine

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sriracha&display=swap');


body h1 {
    font-family: 'Sriracha', sans-serif ;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;

}



#top-stories{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;

}

section {
  max-width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
}




article img {
    max-width:100%;

}

.article-image{

    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
    
    <head>
        
        <title>Best News Ever!</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="This page is a webpage to learn html">
        <meta name="keywords" content="html5,udemy,learn code,">


        <meta name="author" content="Reza Zandi">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial=scale=1.0">

 
    </head>

    <body>
        <header id="main-header">
            <h1>Best News Ever!</h1>

            
        </header>



        <section id="top-stories">
            <article>
                <div class="article-image" style= "background:url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MPV2METPeJU/maxresdefault.jpg)"  ></div>
                <h3>Dog kidnapped by other dog</h3>
                <p>California is no stranger to dog nappings, however, this one takes 
                    the puppies cake... <a href="#">read more..</a></p>
            </article>
        </section>

        <section id="top-stories">
            <article>
                <div class= "article-image" style="background:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Chocolate_%28blue_background%29.jpg)" ></div>
                <h3>Chocolate is actually good for you</h3>
                <p>Scientists have discovered a new propery in chocolate this is good for you. 
                    They discovered that... <a href="#">read more...</a></p>
            </article>
        </section>

        <section id="top-stories">
            <article>
              <div class= "article-image" style="background:url(https://news.cgtn.com/news/77416a4e3145544d326b544d354d444d3355444f31457a6333566d54/img/37d598e5a04344da81c76621ba273915/37d598e5a04344da81c76621ba273915.jpg)" ></div>
              <h3>Cat steals catnip from pet mart</h3>
              <p>A cat in Dallas Texas broke into a petsmart and stole the entire supply of catnip they had.
                  Now that location ... <a href="#">read more...</a></p>
          </article>
      </section>



  </body>


  <footer>
      <br/><br/>
      <center>&copy;2017<br/>
          <a href='#'>Terms of service</a>

      </center>
  </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: This also worked if I wanted to keep the border.